# How to paste predefined texts?

Tags: excel

I use few predefined strings a lot during the creation of data in MS Excel.

Is there a way I can create a drop down option on right click that says "Paste As..." and then select one of the texts I have predefined? Like an add-in.

Or is there some in built Paste option within Excel itself? That would save up loads of time for me.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel Options (via the Office Button) under Proofing you may have an <kbd>AutoCorrect Options...</kbd> button where you can specify `Replace:` and `With:`. So you might choose something like `qq1` (as unlikely to be required as such) to be replaced with `whatever text you prefer to replace qq1`.